# Java : How to Avoid flickering on shape-made only animation (no image file)?

Tags: java, awt, shapes, drawimage

Hi I am reading the book "Programming Video Games for the Evil Genius" by Ian Cinnamon. In one of the projects he explains how to create some animation for a racing game. I wrote a simple code below (removing "almost" everything unnecessary). But the result is the same: **the flickering**.

My question is how, **by using that same code** (with little modifications obviously) can I make it stop flickering? My point is **not to find another way around** (modifying the whole code) because I am already able to create an entire game using **JLabel**, **ImageIcon** classes & spritesheets image files. My point is to solve the flickering problem without removing those shapes [**Rectangle** (fillRect & if possible drawImage)].

By the way if this is not possible "Why would you do that!?" or "It's impossible" are also good answers. (let's try not to use them!)

Thank You!

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Race extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Race();
    }
        private Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(0,0,800,100);
        private Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle(0,100,100,400);
        Image img = null;

    public Race(){
        super("Some Title");
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(800,600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        try{
             URL url= this.getClass().getResource("someImage.png");
            img =Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url);
        }catch(Exception e){}
        Race.GameLoop gameHeart = new Race.GameLoop();
        gameHeart.run();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillRect(r1.x, r1.y, r1.width, r1.height);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(r2.x, r2.y, r2.width, r2.height);
        g.drawImage(img, r2.x, r2.y, r2.width, r2.height, this);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(75);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
        repaint();
    }

    public class GameLoop extends Thread {
        public void run(){
            while(true){
                //game animations and logic
                //even if I put repaint() here it still flicker
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks), for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3256941/230513).

Comment: +1 for an actual working example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't paint onto a top level container (like `JFrame`), they do not support double buffering.

Instead, use something like a `JPanel`

Convention prefers overriding `paintComponent` rather then `paint`.  This is done mostly because `paint` is a actually a very complex method

**NEVER** do this in any `paint` method:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(75);
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
repaint();
```

Firstly, any delays should be handled by the game thread, calling `Thread#sleep` within the paint method will put the Event Dispatching Thread to sleep, which will prevent it from posting events (about mouse and keyboard interactions) and will make your program look non-responsive, which will cause you issues later on.

Never call `repaint` (or any method that might call `repaint`) from inside a paint method.  This is simply asking the repaint manager to schedule another paint cycle, which will chew up your CPU until you program becomes unresponsive.  Again, this is function of your game thread.

Remember, Swing is **NOT** thread save.  All interactions with the UI MUST be made from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  Have a read through [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for some more information

You can take a look at [How to make line animation smoother?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540534/how-to-make-line-animation-smoother/13547895#13547895) and [Java Bouncing Ball](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022754/java-bouncing-ball/13022788#13022788) for an examples

You might like to have a read through [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a quick answer** (if you're too lazy or don't have time to read the documentations given in the answer from MadProgrammer and trashgod which by the way help me writing this one). **But I highly advice you to read the documentation as soon as you have some spare time.**

Here is the code from the question re-written so that there isn't flickering. I separated the code into two classes: the JFrame containing the game in the GameFrame class and the Racing game itself (part of it as in the question) in the Race class which extends JPanel.

**GameFrame.java**

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class GameFrame extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new GameFrame();
    }

    public GameFrame(){
        super("Graphics with JFrame");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(800,600);
        Race game = new Race();
        this.getContentPane().add(game);
        this.setVisible(true);
        game.run();
    }

}
```

**Race.java**

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Race extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    private Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(0,0,800,100);
    private Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle(0,100,100,400);
    Image img = null;

    public Race(){
        try{
             URL url= this.getClass().getResource("someImage.png");
            img =Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url);
        }catch(Exception e){}
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillRect(r1.x, r1.y, r1.width, r1.height);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(r2.x, r2.y, r2.width, r2.height);
        g.drawImage(img, r2.x, r2.y, r2.width, r2.height, this);
}

    public void run() {
        while(true){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(75);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
            repaint();

            //game animations and logic
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks again to MadProgrammer and trashgod. I am sorry I answered to my question instead of commenting others' but I had to show explicitly the difference between Before and After. Again, if you don't understand why I did those modifications to avoid the flickering. Read MadProgrammer and trashgod comments and answers.