# I Need help to move a Image Icon across the screen in java with a Jbutton ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, imageicon

i am doing a program that is like the game Unblockme, where you have to move blocks and get the red one to the other side to move to the next level. Right now i load the program, click level one and then i can select the radiobutton for the Redblock and when i try to then click the move right Jbutton which in the action listener i programmed it to move, and it dosen't ive tryed for like 3 days and im still stuck. Thanks i will include my loading pictures class that loads and draws the imageicons, and my labelframe with has the actionlisteners and everything else. the first class i posted is labelframe then the loading pictures class.

```
    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.io.*;

    public  class LabelFrame extends JFrame{


public LabelFrame( ) 
{
    super("The Structures Game");



    setSize(475,400);
    setLocation(350,200);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);



    JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
    setJMenuBar(menubar);

    JMenu Change = new JMenu("Pick a Level");
    menubar.add(Change);
        JMenu Move = new JMenu("Move keys");
    menubar.add(Move);

    JMenu Options = new JMenu("Options");
    menubar.add(Options);

    JMenu About = new JMenu("About");
    menubar.add(About);

    JMenu Select = new JMenu("Select");
    menubar.add(Select);



    final JMenuItem black = new JMenuItem("Black BackGround");
    Options.add(black);

    final JMenuItem blue = new JMenuItem("Blue BackGround");
    Options.add(blue);

    final JMenuItem yellow = new JMenuItem("Yellow BackGround");
    Options.add(yellow);

    final JMenuItem green = new JMenuItem("Green BackGround");
    Options.add(green);

    final JMenuItem white = new JMenuItem("White BackGround");
    Options.add(white);

    JMenuItem info = new JMenuItem("infomation");
    About.add(info);

    JMenuItem Level1 = new JMenuItem("Level 1");
    Change.add(Level1);


    JMenuItem Level2 = new JMenuItem("Level 2");
    Change.add(Level2);

    JMenuItem Level3 = new JMenuItem("Level 3");
    Change.add(Level3);

    JMenuItem Level4 = new JMenuItem("Level 4");
    Change.add(Level4);

    JMenuItem Level5 = new JMenuItem("Level 5");
    Change.add(Level5);
    final JRadioButton redBlock = new JRadioButton("redblock");
    final JRadioButton blockverticala = new JRadioButton("2blockvertical");
    final JRadioButton blockverticalb = new JRadioButton("4blockvertical");
    final JRadioButton blockhorizontal = new JRadioButton("2blcokhorizontal");

    final JButton moveleft = new JButton("Left");
    final JButton moveright = new JButton("Right");
    final JButton moveup = new JButton("Up");
    final JButton movedown = new JButton("Down");



    Select.add(redBlock);
    Select.add(blockverticala);
    Select.add(blockverticalb);
    Select.add(blockhorizontal);
    Move.add(moveleft);
    Move.add(moveright);
    Move.add(moveup);
    Move.add(movedown);

    Level1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {   
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            final LoadingPictures levelpics = new LoadingPictures(1);

            add(levelpics);
            repaint();


            if(redBlock.isSelected())
            {
                moveright.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                {   
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent right)
                    {
                        //if(right.getSource() = moveright)
                        LoadingPictures.top+=50;

                        levelpics.repaint();
                    }});
            }

            else if(blockverticala.isSelected())
            {
                moveright.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                {   
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent right)
                    {

                    }});
            }

            else if(blockverticalb.isSelected())
            {
                moveright.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                {   
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent right)
                    {

                    }});
            }
            if(blockhorizontal.isSelected())
            {
                moveright.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                {   
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent right)
                    {

                    }});
            }


            black.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {
                    levelpics.setBackground(Color.black);

                }});
            blue.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {
                    levelpics.setBackground(Color.blue);

                }});
            yellow.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {
                    levelpics.setBackground(Color.yellow);

                }});
            green.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {
                    levelpics.setBackground(Color.green);

                }});
            white.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {
                    levelpics.setBackground(Color.white);

                }});


            }


    });






    info.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {   
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"•This is our Final project for computer programming 3 \n" +
                                            "•Created by Jon Eagle and Nick Bonaventure\n•Based off of the " +
                                            "game by KIRA GAmes called UnBlock Me");
                        }});


}
```

}

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Graphics;

    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;


    public class LoadingPictures extends JPanel{

ImageIcon block = new ImageIcon ("2block.jpg");
ImageIcon block4vertical = new ImageIcon("4block.jpg");
ImageIcon redblock = new ImageIcon("redblockhorizontal.jpg");

static int top = 0;
static int topleft = 200;
private int j;
public LoadingPictures(int i)
{
    super();
    j = i;



}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if (j == 1)
    {

        g.drawImage(block4vertical.getImage(),300,200,this);
        g.drawImage(block.getImage(),200,200,this);
        g.drawImage(redblock.getImage(),top,topleft,this);
    }
}




    }
```

Comment: You will want to look up the tutorial on Swing Timer and use one for your animation.

Comment: I just did im looking at it, and will it still work with my Jbutton so it ony moves when the button is clicked?

Comment: Why include the overhead of an ImageIcon just to load an image? Use ImageIO instead, it's more direct.

Answer (score 5):

This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5797965/230513) moves a line using buttons or the keyboard. You can call `drawImage()` in `paintComponent()` instead of `drawLine()`. The essential step is to call `repaint()` after each change in position.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to trashgods example, you could also check out

- [Java Bouncing Ball](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022754/java-bouncing-ball/13022788#13022788)
- [How to make line animation smoother?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540534/how-to-make-line-animation-smoother/13547895#13547895)

While a little off topic, animation is complex topic.  There are number of really good open source Swing based animation libraries you could use to make your life easier...

- [Timing Framework](http://java.net/projects/timingframework)
- [Trident](http://kenai.com/projects/trident/pages/Home)

Both are excellent and are based around a similar theory, but do different things.  You will have to determine if they are suitable for you needs.

Comment: I will look at them, thanks for the help. I am a intermediate beginner some of this looks out that looks out of my knowledge, but i am gonna try it.

Comment: So long as you have a basic understanding of the paint process & concurrency in Swing, you should be right

Comment: @NickB: Good. That's how you move on out of intermediate beginner range.

Comment: I have got it to work, i ended not using the suggestions but i will use them to learn from, i need to make my radiobutton an action listener and then had to put the jbutton inside that. Thanks for all the help!