# Stop flickering in swing when i repaint too much

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, repaint, event-dispatch-thread

I am making an RPG with a tilemap. To generate the tilemap i loop through a 2 dimensional array but that means that when I repaint I have to do that each time. If I repaint too much the screen flickers how could I stop this.

```
package sexyCyborgFromAnOtherDimension;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Game extends JPanel
{
    KeyLis listener;
    int mapX = 20;
    int mapY = 20;
    boolean up = false;
    boolean down = false;
    boolean right = false;
    boolean left = false;
    String[][] map;

    public Game()
    {
        super();
        try 
        {
            map = load("/maps/map1.txt");
        } 

        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        listener = new KeyLis();
        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.requestFocus();
        this.addKeyListener(listener);

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                if(up)
                {
                    mapY++;
                    repaint();
                }

                if(down)
                {
                    mapY--;
                    repaint();
                }

                if(right)
                {
                    mapX--;
                    repaint();
                }

                if(left)
                {
                    mapX++;
                    repaint();
                }
            }
        };
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 10);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) 
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        setDoubleBuffered(true);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        for (int x = 0; x < map.length; x++) 
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < map[x].length; y++) 
            {
                switch(map[x][y])
                {
                case "0":
                    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                    break;
                case "1":
                    g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
                    break;
                }

                g.fillRect(y*20+mapX, x*20+mapY, 20, 20);
            }
        }
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(400, 400, 20, 20);
    }

    String[][] load(String file) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream(file)));
        int lines = 1;
        int length = br.readLine().split(" ").length;
        while (br.readLine() != null) lines++;
        br.close();
        BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream(file)));
        String[][] map = new String[lines][length];
        for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++)
        {
            String line = br1.readLine();
            String[] parts = line.split(" ");
            for (int y = 0; y < length; y++)
            {
                map[i][y] = parts[y];
            }
        }
        br1.close();
        return map;
    }

    private class KeyLis extends KeyAdapter 
    {   
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
        {
            switch (e.getKeyCode())
            {
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                up = true;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                down = true;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                left = true;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                right = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) 
        {
            switch (e.getKeyCode())
            {
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                up = false;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                down = false;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                left = false;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                right = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help

### Edit

Using `javax.swing.Timer` removes all flickering even with a 10 ms delay.

Comment: +1 for your package name.

Comment: @Qwerky indeed nice - but not complying to java naming conventions <g>

Comment: @kleopatra Ok i will change it to com.sexyCyborgFromAnOtherDimension.

Comment: the domain is not the point: package names shouldn't contain uppercase letters :-)

Comment: several thingies wrong with your code (may be unrelated to the problem) a) override paintComponent for custom painting (_not_ paint) b) don't change the component's state in a paint method c) favour KeyBindings over KeyListeners Other than that: 10ms looks like a very tight loop...

Comment: good point because 10ms looks like to overload latency for standard Native OS

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A number of small things jump out at me.

Firstly.  You might be better using `javax.swing.Timer` instead of `java.util.Timer`, this will at least allow the events to flow a little better.

Secondly, 10 milliseconds is to short a time period, seriously, you don't need 100fps, 60fps is about 17 milliseconds, I normally use 40 milliseconds for 25fps.  This might give the EDT some breathing room to actually respond to the repaint requests.

Thirdly, you should be using `paintComponent` instead of `paint`.  It's low enough in the call chain to guaranteed to be double buffered

Fourthly, you should avoid calling any method that might reschedule a `repaint` (like `setDoubleBuffered` for example, to this in the constructor if you must, but, Swing components are double buffered by default)

Fifthly, where possible, paint all "static" or slow changing content to a backing buffer and paint that instead.  This will increase the speed at which `paint` can work as it doesn't get stuck in a lot of small loops.

You may want to take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details about the paint process

Some additional examples...

- [Swing animation running extremely slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14886232/swing-animation-running-extremely-slow/14902184#14902184) - was able to go from 500 elements up to 4500 elements moving on the screen at one time - talks about resource management as well
- [Java Bouncing Ball](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022754/java-bouncing-ball/13022788#13022788)
- [How to make line animation smoother?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540534/how-to-make-line-animation-smoother/13547895#13547895)
- [the images are not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12642852/the-images-are-not-loading/12648265#12648265)

And because kleo scares me (and it's also a good idea), you should also take a look at [How to use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), which will solve your focus issues with the `KeyListener`

Comment: Ok I have very little flickering now :)

Comment: @sanchixx Then you're still doing something wrong, there should no flickering.  If you take time to look over some of the examples I linked, you should find that none of them suffer from any flickering at all

Comment: I have no more flickering

Answer (score 0):

You have set double buffering on the panel, but the things you are drawing on it yourself are not being double buffered. Calling `setDoubleBuffered(true)` only applies buffering for child components of the container.

You need manually buffer stuff you draw yourself.

I would suggest moving away from a `JPanel` and use a `Canvas` instead. Have a look at how a `Canvas` is used with a buffer strategy in [this class](https://github.com/qwerky/Towers/blob/master/src/main/java/lineup/ui/UI.java), where it can handle hundreds of things being drawn on screen with perfect smoothness and no flickering (the game runs on a 10ms sleep loop too).

Comment: Or use `paintComponent` instead of `paint` where it is double buffered...and using `javax.swing.Timer` wouldn't hurt either

Comment: not really true: the RepaintManager bubbles up repaint request to the nearest parent that is doubleBuffered. JPanel is so by default, even if it set to not doubleBuffered, the rootPane is :-)

Comment: @MadProgrammer - just noticed he's calling `super.paintComponent()` from inside `paint()` :S

Comment: @Qwerky Well, that's going to screw things up :P

Comment: @kleopatra Thanks for the additional info, nice to know

Answer (score -1):

Not really sure if it solves your problem, but you can consider to use a 1dimensional array.

when `int width;` is the width of your screen/tile/whatever you loop and `int height` is the height you coud do the following:

instead of, what you do:

```
for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
{
    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        // dosomething with your array
        myarray[x][y];
    }
}
```

you could go through this way

```
for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        // dosomething with your array
        myarray[x + y * width];
    }
}
```

Comment: That would not solve my problem and I like using a 2 dimensional array.